# Analysis (sequences of $\sin (a_n⋅x))$

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis

Let $(a_n)$ - a sequence of positive integers. Could it be that for any real number $x$ from the interval $[0; 1]$ the sequence of $\sin (a_n⋅x)$ converges?

*If the sequence $(a_n)$ converges, and the second sequence converges. This is a very important point, but the sequence of natural numbers rarely converge ...*

Comment: Well, if the interval is $[0;1]$, I can find such $x$. It may be harder with $(0;1]$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the sequence $1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,\ldots$. If $\sin(a_nx)$ converges then we must have $\sin x=\sin 2x=\sin 3x$.
As $\sin x\ne 0$ for $0<x<1$, we find from $\sin x=\sin 2x=2\sin x\cos x$ that  $\cos x=\frac12$ and $x=\frac \pi 3$. But then $\sin 3x=0\ne\sin x$.