# The sequences of $\sin (a_n⋅x)$

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis

Let $a_n$ be an increasing sequence of positive integers. Could it be that for any real number $x$ from the interval $[0;1]$ the sequence $\sin(a_n \cdot x)$ converges as $n→∞$?

*due to poor knowledge of English, I incorrectly formulated his  [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1670748/analysis-sequences-of-sin-a-n%E2%8B%85x)*

Comment: It converges for $x=0$.

Comment: It's clear. What if $x \not = 0$?

Comment: I expect such a response as a @Ivan Neretin

Comment: It required either to provide the sequence in which the convergence is always present, or to solve the following problem: given a sequence, find the X, in which there is convergence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, this surely can happen for *some* sequences and some values of $x$. Say, $a_n=n!,\;x=2\pi e$ (or $2\pi(e-{8\over3})$, if you insist on $0<x\le1$); then $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\sin(a_n\cdot x)=0$.

> See, $e=\sum\limits_{i=0}^\infty{1\over i!}$. When we multiply that by $n!$, the terms up to $1\over n!$ turn to integers, and what remains is $n!\left({1\over(n+1)!}+{1\over(n+2)!}+\dots\right)={1\over n+1}+{1\over(n+1)(n+2)}+\dots<{1\over n}$, so $|\sin(2\pi e\cdot n!)|<{2\pi\over n}\mathop{\longrightarrow}\limits_{n\to\infty}0$

If you have a sequence and want to find $x$ (besides the obvious $x=0$), that's **not** always possible.

If you have $x$ and want to find the sequence, it **is** always possible. But different values of $x$ would require different sequences; there is no "universal" sequence that would work for all (or "almost all") $x$.

Comment: Just wanted to share a curious (if somewhat far-fetched) example. (Yes, it does converge, despite $x$ not being an integer multiple of $\pi$; think of $e=1+1+{1\over2!}+{1\over3!}+{1\over4!}+\dots$). Of course, yours would suffice just as well.

Comment: Yes, I see.  $n! e$ gets "close" to an integer for large $n$.  And inasmuch as the sine is continuous and $\sin (0)=0$, then it works!!  Well done!  +1 -Mark

Answer (score 1):

At least the reverse holds: for every $x$, there exists some increasing sequence of integers $(a_n)$ (depending on $x$!) such that $\sin(a_n \cdot x)$ converges. This is just sequential compactness of $[0,1]$. But as there are as many $x \in [0,1]$ as there are increasing integer sequences, conceivably the reverse could also hold, though it seems unlikely: and (added) [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1670766/4280) shows it is in fact false.

Comment: But the sequence in that answer is not increasing.

Comment: True indeed. I still think it's false

Answer (score 1):

Let $\{a_n\}$ be an strictly increasing sequence of integers. Then $\{\sin(a_n\,x)\}$ does not converge almost everywhere. Suppose to the contrary that $\{\sin(a_n\,x)\}$ converges almost everywhere. Then $(\sin(a_{n+1}x)-\sin(a_nx))^2$ converges almost everywhere to $0$. By the dominated convergence theorem
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_0^{2\pi}(\sin(a_{n+1}x)-\sin(a_nx))^2\,dx=0,
$$
a contradiction since
$$
\int_0^{2\pi}(\sin(a_{n+1}x)-\sin(a_nx))^2\,dx=2\,\pi.
$$

Comment: I included that hypothesis. The OP says increasing. There are two possibilities then: either the sequence is eventually constant, or converges to $\infty$, in which case we can adjust the argument in the answer.

Comment: But if the sequence is not eventually constant, there are an infinite number of $n$'s where $a_n<a_{n+1}$, which is what I meant when I said that the argument can be adjusted. Of course if the sequence is eventually constant there is nothing to prove.

Comment: As I explained, in that case there are an infinite Numbers of jumps, and the argumenta carries over.